# SNMP (Windows and Linux) update intervall

Tags: linux, windows, snmp

I'm writing an application in c# using snmpsharpnet to read information like cpu load, processes cpu and memory usage and so on.

I notice that the values that the snmp bulk return are always the same and only after 30-35 seconds they change!!

How can i change te update interval of the snmp data ? I need to obtain the data every 5 s on windows and linux

Thanks!

Comment: Ser https://www.fineconnection.com/how_to_set_the_net-snmp_agent_update_or_counter_refresh_interval/

Comment: thanks for the comment do you know if there is a simil table on windows?